# How to redirect www to non-www globally in nginx?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, redirect

I know how to redirect to non-www for a single site within nginx, but I have a lot of sites.

So how can I do that globally for all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
server {
         server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
         return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I would user `.+` instead of `.*` in the capture group, although it doesn't change much.